# iOS 8 keyboard extension - able to use Apple default keyboard template xib?

Tags: ios, keyboard, ios8, ios-app-extension

I was wondering if, in the process of creating and testing the keyboard extension, whether I am able to use something like the default Apple QWERTY keyboard to test functions. I saw that the recommended steps as shown in several tutorials is to use a custom XIB to add buttons, but was wondering if keyboard template is available to use.

Is there isn't an Apple keyboard to use, is there a popular 3rd party/open source keyboard template that is available?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an Apple keyboard to use. I think its hard to find a completed iOS8 keyboard extension template, but you can find some Custom keyboard projects on github that gives you the main idea , search for it .

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Here is a github project targeting iOS 8 and Swift in case it helps other viewers of the question: https://github.com/archagon/tasty-imitation-keyboard